# Spring MVC 4 Global Basic HTTP Authentication

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, basic-authentication, spring-java-config, spring-4

I need to set up global basic HTTP authentication for a staging server. Nothing fancy. I just want to require username/password to access *anything*. I also would like to use only Java config. I've experimented with a lot of different solutions, but none of them working. I'm always able to access all resources on the server. This is what I'm doing now:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

   @Override
   protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Configuring HttpSecurity");

    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .httpBasic();
   }

   @Autowired
   public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Configuring global AuthenticationManagerBuilder");

    auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
   }
}
```

I can see in the logs that these snippets are being executed. As you can see, in the first method, I am requiring that all requests are authenticated. In the second method, I am specifying in memory authentication.

Comment: whats the error that you are getting ? and also how did you try to login ? need more information to the question

Comment: There is no error. The issue is that I'm not prompted to perform basic HTTP authentication. I want to always require basic HTTP authentication whenever any resource is requested.

Answer (score 0):

Your SOP statements are getting printed (while container instantiation) because of @Configuration (which is again not required as it is also declared by @EnableWebSecurity). You still need to register the spring security filter chain in your web.xml or MVC initializer class that extends [WebMvcConfigurerAdapter](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.html) or implements [WebApplicationInitializer](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.html) if you wish to use it with the application filter chain. For example (java config as you are looking for the same):

```
EnumSet<DispatcherType> dispatcherTypes = EnumSet.of(
            DispatcherType.REQUEST, DispatcherType.ERROR);
container.addFilter("springSecurityFilterChain",
            DelegatingFilterProxy.class).addMappingForUrlPatterns(
            dispatcherTypes, false, "/*");
```

where container is an instance of ServletContext.